# How to run as console and window GUI application

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to show a console for log or probably anyone here can suggest me the references of creating log via GUI? I use Java on Netbeans

If I choose a window GUI application from running a built jar file, I can't see the log or console running, too

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, ypu jar is a runnable, but ypu can still run it from the Console...
open a terminal, navigate to the jar path and run it by calling `"java -jar yourJar.jar"`... and all the system.out and system.err will be displayed there...

Comment: thanks it works if I was running it on Console with `java - jar <file>.jar` and opened as GUI, but if have converted to .exe file. How to run it like that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have application with console as well as GUI is to create a command line application and then running an instance of JFrame ( or which ever other GUI library you want to use )  from the console application.

Following is code example with console and Jframe UI

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class ConsoleJFrameCombo extends JFrame {



         // JPanel
        JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
        // Buttons
        JButton btnAddFlight = new JButton("Click me");



        public ConsoleJFrameCombo() {

            initUI();


        }

        private void initUI() {


            btnAddFlight.setBounds(60, 400, 220, 30);

            // JPanel bounds
            pnlButton.setBounds(800, 800, 200, 100);

            // Adding to JFrame
            pnlButton.add(btnAddFlight);
            add(pnlButton);

            btnAddFlight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("OUtput to console");

                }
            });


            setTitle("Simple example");
            setSize(300, 200);

            setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            //chnge to exit on close to exit program. 
            setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

                    ConsoleJFrameCombo ex = new ConsoleJFrameCombo();
                    ex.setVisible(true);


                    System.out.println("Press Enter to  exit");

                    System.in.read();
                    System.out.println("Exiting....");
                    System.exit(0);

        }
    }
```

Comment: So, you mean I need to convert an existing application to headless mode?

Comment: Im sorry headless mode is only for systems which dosen't have any GUI